# What is a suitable backend for relayjs?

Tags: relayjs

I am having trouble understanding how to hook up a backend that will support relayjs. Does GraphQL/Relay automatically help store queries? I.e. if I implement a REST backend that returns a json blob with everything, will Relay take care of the data query optimizations? I'm not entirely sure of the abstraction between Relay and backend/database.

Comment: SO is a forum for specific programming questions. Please narrow down your overly-broad question to something more specifc.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/getting-started.html) in the Relay documentation. Relay requires that you have a GraphQL server that understands GraphQL queries and can respond with valid response payloads.

GraphQL provides an abstraction with which Relay uses to interface with your backend. GraphQL is not a database, but rather a layer that sits on top of your server application code. For example, you could implement a GraphQL server that sits in front of your REST server as demonstrated by the **graphql/swapi-graphql** repository.

[Nick Schrock's presentation of GraphQL at @Scale 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_9RgHXqH8J0) also provides a good overview.

Comment: Also potentially useful if you want to re-use things built by other people is [the awesome-graphql](https://github.com/chentsulin/awesome-graphql) list ("Awesome list of GraphQL & Relay").